# array_search return comparison differentiation

Tags: php

I want to use `array_search` to detect if a match is found using an if statement.

- `array_search()` returns empty '' when no match is found
- `array_search()` returns 0 when the match is indexed to 0
- `array_search()` returns a number other than 0 when a match is indexed to a non-zero value

if I use != '' the problem is that 0 is equivalent to '' in PHP. How do I get around this with one if statement?

edit: whoops- `array_search()` does not return empty, it returns `false`.

Comment: Use the type-strong comparsion !== eg. `if ($ret !== '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns `false`, not `''` if no match is found. As you point out, that is the same as 0 in a simple equality comparison ([`==` or `!=`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)) because `false` can be [type juggled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to `0`, so you need to do a strict equality test ([`===` or `!==`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)) which also takes into account the type of the operands. Since `false` is boolean and `0` is an integer, this check will fail. So write something like this:

```
$key = array_search($value, $array);
if ($key !== false) {
    // found
}
else {
    // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use array_search to detect if a match is found using an if statement.

Just a suggestion - it's possible you don't need to use `array_search`.

If it's just a matter of determining whether or not something is present in the array, you can use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead, which only returns `true` or `false`.

If you need to know the specific index this won't be useful, but it's *slightly* simpler if you don't.